# How to pass the file as a input to the array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, curl

I am new to linux, After running the sequence of commands i have an output in a file.
Now I need to pass this file into an array and i need to push into **Influxdb**

Output of the file is like below:

```
daily/A1D05181200052209001 482668
daily/A1D05181200052212001 513278
daily/A1D05181200052215001 482668
daily/A1D05181200052218001 513278
daily/A1D05181200052221001 482668
daily/A1D05181200052300001 513278
daily/A1D05181200052303001 482668
```

so as of now i tried to give file as an input to array like below

```
mapfile -t myArray < $FILESIZE5
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < $FILESIZE5 > $FILESIZE4
cat $FILESIZE4
```

When i run the above command am getting the output like

```
    daily/A1D05181200052209001 482668
    daily/A1D05181200052212001 513278
    daily/A1D05181200052215001 482668
    daily/A1D05181200052218001 513278
    daily/A1D05181200052221001 482668
    daily/A1D05181200052300001 513278
    daily/A1D05181200052303001 482668
```

But what i need to do is like...i need to give the command to insert the values in the influx db.
Command will be like

```
curl -i -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=S3ck&precision=s" --data-binary "ecmwfarchiveold,bucketpath=ecmwf-archive/daily/A1D05181200052209001 size=482668"
```

I need to give this curl command in the array so that values can be inserted into the db.
Can anyone pls help me out on this!

Am taking the files starting with **A1D0518** from S3bucket and storing it in a file

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ui-dl-weather-ecmwf-ltf --prefix daily/ --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'A1D0518')]" --output text | awk '{print $2, $4}' >> "$FILESIZE"

sed 's/awsadmin//g' "$FILESIZE" > "$FILESIZE1"
grep '[^[:blank:]]' < "$FILESIZE1" > "$FILESIZE5"

#cat $FILESIZE5
wc -l $FILESIZE5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the out put directory.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r first second; do
  curl -i -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=S3ck&precision=s" --data-binary "ecmwfarchiveold,bucketpath=ecmwf-archive/daily/$first size=$second"
done < <(command_that_genereates_the_output)
```

Comment: instead of redirecting to a file the out put of the command, you can use process substitution `<( )`

Comment: I gave like this `while read -r first second; do
echo curl -i -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=S3check&precision=s" --data-binary "testecmwftrack,bucketpath=daily/$first size=$second"
done` But pls let me know where should i give the input file i.e  **$FILESIZE5**

Comment: what is filesize5? is that the array?

Comment: Like i said, you can skip the file/array creation, just use the sequence of commands that generates the output inside the `<( )`, or if you really like the file put it after the `done` e.g. `done < "$filesize5"`  although you can really put it before the loop but just for readability put it after the `done`

Comment: **$FILESIZE5** is the file that has the contents mentioned in the question section `daily/A1D05181200052209001 482668 etc`

Comment: I will post the sequence of commands in the quetion section...pls let me know is it okay to post these sequence of commands into <()

Comment: Add it to your question post.

Comment: I have posted the sequence of commands in the question section..Could u pls help me out on this @Jetchisel

Comment: You can use the file right? Just use the file `done < "$FILESIZE5"` or if you can post a simple output of the `aws`

Comment: **daily/A1D05181200052209001 482668** in this sequence i posted my final output of the aws

Comment: Ok so "$FILESIZE4" is the final output, use that `done < "$FILESIZE4"` instead of the procsub I have in my post.